# GLMM model validity

Tags: mixed-model, glmm

I have fitted a glmm model using glmmTMB and DHARMa packages in R. The model is pretty perfect: neither overdispersed/zero-inflated or spatially autocorrelated. And the qq plot of observed vs. expected residuals is straight.

However, the predictions from the model are extreme nonsensical values (I have limited the y axis to 0,5000. There are values that go up to 1e18):
[image: Predicted response variable]
[image: Raw response variable]

This is an indication that I am trying to fit a linear model on a phenomena that is not linear, and that I need probably to look into generalized additive models to better represent the data.

However, the goal of my modeling approach is not to predict the response variable, but to **find the optimal  value range of each predictor variable for increase in the response variable accounting for the random effect of spatial position.**

I have looked over each of the predictor vs response variable plots and they seem to overlap nicely. So my question is: **am I able to use this model to determine the optimal predictor value range for increase in response variable even though the model provides extreme prediction values?**

**Edit 1**
The outcome variable is count data of a grasshopper species in eastern Australia.

I am fitting a negative binomial 2 model with an offset to account for sampling intensity. I have two random effects which are bioregions and landuse code. X and Y are spatial coordinates and Y_avg and X_avg are coordinates on a soil composition (sand %/silt %/clay %) ternary plot. Here is the equation I used in R:

```
glmmTMB(Nymph_Dens ~ NTO_avg + SOC_avg + BDW_avg + X + Y +
       Y_avg + X_avg + TPI + Wood_Mode  + offset(Join_Count) + (1|REG_NAME_7) + (1|LU_CODE), 
       data = dat,ziformula=~0, family = "nbinom2")
```

Comment: What is the outcome variable in your model and on what scale is it measured? Also, can you offer more details about the glmm model that you fitted to the data?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement I have edited the question with answers.

Comment: So, looking at the $y$-axis of both graphs, is the trouble that you are predicting counts up to 100 times more than expected (i.e. the observed counts)? Are the scales different? How are you obtaining these predictions?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned, I constrained the y axis to 0,5000. The actual point value goes up to 1e-18.

Comment: Thank you for your edits. I am assuming by density you mean count? Can you also define what you mean by "optimal value range for each predictor variable for increase in response"? For the predictors with _avg in their name, how was the averaging done?

Comment: Are you using `predict(..., type = 'response')`?

Comment: It would be more useful to add a plot of predicted versus actual nymph density.  But @Alex has a good point - did you predict by setting random effects to zero?

Comment: yes, I used predict(..., type= “response”)

Comment: what is the log-likelihood of your model versus a model without the random effects and zero inflation?

Comment: Log liklihood with random effects: -42453.7 and without: -42700.7

Comment: @IsabellaGhement, By, 'optimal value range,' I mean the range of the predictor value that  leads to increase in the response variable. What I am trying to do is take those predictor values and create a 'heat map' of their habitat range of favorable locations.

Upon saying that, I am now realizing that I am trying to receive a nonlinear answer from a linear model. Probably not the best approach.